# Passing location data from fragment to activity in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

When the user long clicks on a mapFragment I want to send data about the clicked location to another activity, ie. I want to pass lat, long, city, zip code, country... to LocationDetailsActivity.

I successfully passed lat and the long, but I got stuck with everything else. I am a beginner both in coding and android so I use step-by-step examples and so far I couldn't find any step-by-step examples for this.

Code:

```
    if (myLocation != null) {
        latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    }

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> allAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude, 1);
                  if (allAddresses.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = allAddresses.get(0);
                      String addressline = allAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                      String city = allAddresses.get(0).getLocality();
                      String state = allAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                      String country = allAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                      String postalCode = allAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("latitude", arg0.latitude);
            intent.putExtra("longitude", arg0.longitude);
            intent.putExtra("city",);
            intent.putExtra("zip",);
            intent.putExtra("country",);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: make your city, zipcode variable global so that it's can be access outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> allAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude, 1);
                  if (allAddresses.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = allAddresses.get(0);

                     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationDetailsActivity.class);
                     intent.putExtra("latitude", arg0.latitude);
                     intent.putExtra("longitude", arg0.longitude);
                     intent.putExtra("city", allAddresses.get(0).getLocality());
                     intent.putExtra("zip", allAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode());
                     intent.putExtra("state", allAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
                     intent.putExtra("country", allAddresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                     startActivity(intent);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I get this error: _Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final_. I declared these variables final, but then I get this error. variable city might not have been initialized

Comment: I still get this error: _Variable "city" is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final_

Comment: I get no error, I will test this tonight or tomorrow but I believe this is it :) thank a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You can move you `startActivity` code inside the `longClickListener` or you can define all the variables globally to use them outside the `clickListener`

```
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> allAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude, 1);
          if (allAddresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = allAddresses.get(0);
              String addressline = allAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
              String city = allAddresses.get(0).getLocality();
              String state = allAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
              String country = allAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
              String postalCode = allAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode();


    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("latitude", arg0.latitude);
    intent.putExtra("longitude", arg0.longitude);
    intent.putExtra("city",city);
    intent.putExtra("zip",postalCode);
    intent.putExtra("country",country);
    startActivity(intent);


        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
});
```

Comment: When I try this code I get "cannot resolve symbol" errors for ctiy, postalCode and country and when I add global variables outside setOnclickListener i get "variable city have not been initialized".

Comment: are u using the posted code inside the if statement scope ?

Answer (score 2):

```
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> allAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(arg0.latitude, arg0.longitude, 1);
              if (allAddresses.size() > 0) {
                moveToLoginActivity(address,arg0.latitude,arg0.longitude); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});


function void moveToLoginActivity(Address address, float latitude, float longitude){

    Address address = allAddresses.get(0);
    addressline = allAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city = allAddresses.get(0).getLocality();
    String  = allAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    String country = allAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    String postalCode = allAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode();


    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
    intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
    intent.putExtra("city",city);
    intent.putExtra("state",state);
    intent.putExtra("country",country);
    intent.putExtra("zip",postalCode);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I get this error: _Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final_, then I declare these variables final, and I get this error. _variable city might not have been initialized_